# How do I open full screen VMWare?

Tags: vmware

I already tried to install VMWware tools but it tell me that I downloaded it already so I reinstalled it.

It is not full screen. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: i need it for work so help me .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you probably want to go to Edit, Preferences, Display. Choose Autofit Guest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your screenshot shows that you maximized the Workstation window.  You did not enter *full screen mode* as implied by your question.
2. If you mean how do you make the guest resolution fill the Workstation window, then you must go to **Edit > Preferences > Display > Autofit** and enable **Autofit Guest**.
3. If you actually do want to use *full screen mode*, you additionally will need to go to **Edit > Preferences > Display > Full screen** and select **Autofit Guest**.  You can enter and exit full screen mode by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Enter or choosing **View > Full Screen**.
4. You alternatively could choose **View > Fit Guest Now** to manually cause the guest resolution to fill the available space.